# How can I use a variadic template to define a type inside the class?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to be able to typedef a type *f* inside a class to be an std::function that takes a number of parameters, the number and type of which depends on the template parameter of the class, like this:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename ... Args>
class SomeClass
{
    typedef std::function<void(Args)> f;
};
```

However, this does not work. g++ with -std=c++0x bails out with "error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’.

I am trying to wrap my head around a bunch of new C++11 features, and it is quite possible that I am missing a very obvious solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what wrong and how you can solve it... Add the ellipsis:

```
typedef std::function<void(Args...)> f;
```